# How to display Prometheus labels with Grafana alert

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am using Grafana alerts with a Prometheus data source.

Everything works fine but I receive notifications like this:

```
[Alerting] Disk Usage % $instance
Message: Disk usage warning $instance
```

(Note my failed attempt to resolve a Prometheus label value in the alert name and message.)

To find out which instance has the memory problem I have to go into Grafana. I'm hoping there is a way to resolve Prometheus labels in Grafana alert notification names/messages. I'm aware I can perform alerting in Prometheus with bells and whistles, but I'd rather configure my alerts using the Grafana's dashboard, which seems adequate apart for this one desirable feature.

Comment: Could you share one alert / configuration as a (blurred) screenshot? Because I'm pretty sure that my Grafana alerts contain the legend attribute name of the specific line crossing the respective alert threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like current Grafana version v7.1.5 doesn't support it:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5848